# Does $\lim_{x \to 1^{-}} \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} (x^n - x^{n+1})\log{(1+x^{n+1})} = 0$?

Tags: limits, summation

Is it true that
$$\lim_{x \to 1^{-}} \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} (x^n - x^{n+1})\log{(1+x^{n+1})} = 0$$

I'm not entirely sure whether or not this sum tends to 0, since the similar sum $\lim_{x \to 1^{-}} \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} x^n - x^{n+1}$ tends to 1 (in fact the sum is 1 for all $0 < x < 1$).

I've tried to see if the dominated convergence theorem applies so that the limit can be moved inside the sum, but the best dominating values I could come up with were bounding $\log(1+x^{n+1})$ by $\log{(2)}$ and then setting $x = \frac{n}{n+1}$ for the $n$th term. This gives $\log{2}\left(1-\frac{1}{n+1}\right)^n\frac{1}{n+1}$ which is approximately $\frac{\log{2}}{e} \frac{1}{n+1}$ whose sum doesn't converge so I can't use the dominated convergence theorem.

I've also tried obtaining bounds using the fact that $\log{(1+x^{n+1})} < x^{n+1}$ and was only able to show that the limit of the sum is less than $\lim_{x \to 1^{-}} \frac{x}{1+x}$, so less than $\frac{1}{2}$.

Comment: The summand is nonnegative, no? Then how is it summing to zero?

Comment: The summand is non-negative for any fixed $0 < x < 1$. However, the sums could still converge to zero as $x$ tends to 1. As the simplest example, consider an "infinite" sum $f(x) = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} a_n$ where the first term $a_0 = 1-x$ and the remaining terms $a_n = 0$ for $n > 0$. Then $f(x) = 1-x$ which is non-zero for all $0 < x < 1$, but $\lim_{x \to 1} f(x) = 0$.

Comment: Oh, I forgot there is a limit in front.

Answer (score 2):

\begin{align}
|x|<1\implies&\phantom{={}}\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}(x^n-x^{n+1})\log(1+x^{n+1})
\\&=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}(x^n-x^{n+1})\sum_{m=1}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^{m-1}}{m}x^{m(n+1)}
\\&=\sum_{m=1}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^{m-1}}{m}\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}x^{n(m+1)}(x^m-x^{m+1})
\\&=\sum_{m=1}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^{m-1}}{m}\frac{x^m-x^{m+1}}{1-x^{m+1}}
\\&=\sum_{m=1}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^{m-1}}{m}\frac{x^m}{1+x+\ldots+x^m}.
\end{align}
Compare to [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3201818/543769) of mine. (The limit is equal to $\color{blue}{2\ln 2-1}$.)

Comment: Ah fantastic, thanks! That was the original question I was looking at and I was told the answer was supposed to be $\sqrt{e}$ which would imply the limit is 0, but I had a hard time proving it. No wonder, since the limit isn't 0!